# Selecting 3 distinct elements from $\{2^1, 2^2,\ldots, 2^{2000}\}$ such that they form a GP.

Tags: combinatorics

Compute the number of sets of three distinct ele­ments that can be chosen from the set $\{2^1, 2^2,\ldots, 2^{2000}\}$ such that the three elements form an increasing geometric progression.

This is a problem from ARML 2001. I was thinking of classifying the set into subsets of odd and even power of $2$ but that does not work very effectively. I would prefer a conceptually elegant way over a rigorous computation. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the powers can form an arithmetic progression

Comment: We wish to calculate the number of 3 term arithmetic progressions in $\{1,2,...2000\}$. Now given a triple $\{a,b,c\}$ this forms an arithmetic progression provided $b=\frac{a+c}{2}$ so you could count pairs $a$ and $c$ whose average is an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David said, this is the same as selecting three exponents in arithmetic progression. Clearly the first and last exponent determine the middle exponent, and they (the first and last) must have the same parity. Therefore it amounts to choosing a pair either from $\{1,3,\ldots,1999\}$ or from $\{2,4,\ldots,2000\}$, for a total of
$$
 2\times\binom{1000}2 = 1000\times 999 = 999000
$$
possibilities.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was trying to see this by odd-even subset classification, but couldn't. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as selecting three elements of $\{1,2,\ldots,2000\}$ to form an arithmetic progression.  First we choose the middle element $b$ to be anything from $2$ to $1000$; then choose the smallest element $a$ to be anything from $1$ to $b-1$.  This uniquely determines the largest element $c$.  The number of possibilities is
$$\sum_{b=2}^{1000}(b-1)=\frac{999\times1000}{2}\ .$$

Similarly, if we choose $b$ from $1001$ to $1999$ we then proceed to choose $c$, and this uniquely determines $a$.  This gives the same number of possibilities as the first case, so the grand total is $999000$.

Comment: There's a $2000$ in the problem statement.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks, fixed.  Don't know how I misread that... maybe it was all the $2$s in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I developed a very nice concept while trying to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Number of GPs in which the difference-factor is $2^1$ is 1998.
$(2^1\to 2^2\to 2^3)\cdots (2^{1998}\to 2^{1999}\to 2^{2000})$

Number of GPs in which the difference-factor is $2^2$ is 1996.
$(2^1\to 2^3\to 2^5)\cdots (2^{1996}\to 2^{1998}\to 2^{2000})$

$\cdots$

Number of GPs in which the difference-factor is $2^{998}$ is 4.
$(2^1\to 2^{999}\to 2^{1997})\cdots (2^4\to 2^{1002}\to 2^{2000})$

Number of GPs in which the difference-factor is $2^{999}$ is 2.
$(2^1\to 2^{1000}\to 2^{1999})\cdots (2^2\to 2^{1001}\to 2^{2000})$

Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Interesting....